# programatically adding an on-tap attribute referencing a dart function for a HtmlElement

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, angular-dart, dart-html

I have a dart function:

```
_addSelection(HtmlElement ele){
  ele.classes.add("selection");
}
```

I would either want 1 or 2 things to occur, either *A*) execute an on-tap and on-track function given the *selection* class.... OR  Dynamically add the `on-tap` and `on-track` attributes referencing reflected dart functions.

I have 2 functions:

```
@reflectable
onTap(CustomEventWrapper cew, params){
  //...
}

@reflectable
onTrack(CustomEventWrapper cew, params){
  //...
}
```

I was looking at the `HtmlElement` class and documentation and I wasnt quite understanding how to do this.

**Edit** if I were using jQuery and Javascript, I would be doing something as simple as:

```
$(document).on("tap", function(){});
$(document).on("track", function(){});
```

**Edit2** Added Angular Dart because both designs leverage Dart backend and markup front end.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
_addSelection(HtmlElement ele) {
  ele.classes.add("selection");
  ele.onTouchEnd.listen((TouchEvent touch) {
    ...
  });
}
```

That would give you something close to the `tap` event. If you wanted to get really fancy you could also listen for `onTouchStart` and only call your `onTap` handler when the time between the start and end is small.

Comment: Ill reread the class def, I wasnt sure if Touch was what i wanted, or if i should define listen handlers just like that.  I was thinking there was a more modern way of applying the equivalent of `on-click=""` to an element

Comment: The `tap` event isn't built into Javascript, it's just in jQuery. If you want similar functionality in Dart, you will have to write it yourself using the `Touch` events, or see if someone has already written it in Pub.

Comment: Oh yeah, I was just looking up html5 events and you are right.  I always thought it was.  That is something I could easily create though, thank you.